# Which heading level to use when position in document outline is unknowable?

Tags: html, accessibility, semantic-markup, html-heading

I'm building an HTML snippet that will be dynamically included on a page. The snippet looks something like this:

```
<article>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Content</p>
</article>
```

The problem is that I have no way of knowing where in the document outline this snippet will be included. It may appear directly under the `<h1>`, or it may be nested several levels deep under an `<h4>`. In other words, my outline may look like this:

```
<h1>
    <h2>
        <h3>
    <h2>
    <h2>
```

Pretty logical. Or it may look like this:

```
<h1>
    <h2>
        <h2>
    <h2>
    <h2>
```

Not so logical. Or it may even look like this:

```
<h1>
    <h2>
        <h3>
            <h2>
    <h2>
    <h2>
```

Downright weird, and I have no way of knowing or controlling it!

I'm not concerned about styling, just semantics.

I'd say the best solution would be to just use `<h1>`s everywhere and let sectioning elements handle the semantics per the new HTML5 document outline, but my research has advised me against that because no client actually supports that outlining method. So what is the best solution?

#### Edit

A few ideas have come up in the comments that use scripting to solve the problem. These could work, but I guess I want to know if there is a sensible solution that doesn't require the added complexity of code that does things I think the browser should be doing on its own.

Hypothetically, if such scripting solutions were impossible for whatever reason, would it make sense to create a flat outline using just `<h1>`s rather than create a completely wrong outline with improperly nested sub-levels?

Comment: What type of content will your HTML snippet contain? What type of content will the rest of your page will contain? You could also consider using `<article role="article">` to help improve client support of the article element.

Comment: The contents would vary widely, as would the contents of the rest of the page. This is really a general inquiry for how to handle components that will be included in arbitrary places throughout a website.

Comment: Not an answer, but this is why we need a <h> element which can take on whichever level it needs to fit into the rest of the page structure. https://github.com/ThePacielloGroup/html5-h#html5-h

Comment: It's the responsibility of the snippet-including code to resolve the heading elements to the correct level for the context in which the snippet is being included.

Comment: @Alohci so use javascript or php or something to rewrite the html? I suppose that works, but it feels like doing work that the browser should be doing for me.

Comment: @jcolton - Well I agree. The browser should do the work. Indeed the whole point of the outline algorithm is, or should have been, to do that work. Sadly, the browser makers point blank refused to do that work, blaming the AT vendors for not doing it at their end. But it makes no sense for AT to do the work (JAWS tried and gave up)  because they don't have all the information they need exposed through the platform accessibility APIs. So we're stuck with a totally unsatisfactory situation where web authors have to pick up the pieces as best we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As far as the HTML5 spec is concerned,** you may use any heading element (`h1`-`h6`), as long as you always use a sectioning element (like `article`).

All of these snippets are valid, they create the same outline, and they are semantically equivalent:

```html
<!-- h1 + h2 -->
<body>
  <h1>heading for 'body'</h1>
  <article>
    <h2>heading for 'article'</h2>
  </article>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- h1 + h1 -->
<body>
  <h1>heading for 'body'</h1>
  <article>
    <h1>heading for 'article'</h1>
  </article>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- h1 + h6 -->
<body>
  <h1>heading for 'body'</h1>
  <article>
    <h6>heading for 'article'</h6>
  </article>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- h5 + h1 -->
<body>
  <h5>heading for 'body'</h5>
  <article>
    <h1>heading for 'article'</h1>
  </article>
</body>
```

Because each sectioning element has not more than one heading in these snippets, the heading elements `h1`-`h6` work like the (often proposed) `h` element: the rank doesn’t matter.

**But, like always, some user agents might not follow the spec here,** for various reasons. If you want to convey the intended outline to these UAs, too, you would have to rely on the heading element ranks (like it’s the case in HTML 4.01). That’s why [the spec recommends to do this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/sections.html#creating-an-outline):

> Authors should use heading rank (`h1`-`h6`) to convey document structure.

**What to do if calculating the rank isn’t possible?** Make the best guess¹ possible, and live with a non-ideal outline for UAs that don’t support the full HTML5 outline algorithm. For UAs that support HTML5’s outline algorithm, it will work fine.

---

¹ Guesses like:

- It never should be a `h1`, because your snippet will be a sectioning element, so it starts at least at level 2 in the document (level 1 will always be any heading element with `body` as nearest sectioning parent).
- Depending on the nature of the snippet, low headings will be very unlikely. For example, if the snippet is a comment form for blog posts, it should be on the same level as the `article` element or one level below (if it’s nested inside the `article`), so typically `h2` or `h3`.
- If the snippet represents something very important for users, a higher heading should be used, because with a lower heading users that rely on the outline for navigating might never access the snippet’s content, as it could be "hidden" in the deep outline, below entries the users might possibly have no interest in (so they might skip the whole section with all its children).

Comment: This is basically what I've been doing, and what I'll probably continue to do in the absence of a more universal solution. If nothing else, this answer confirms my gut instincts.